# Trying to generate averages across multiple lists

Tags: r, list

I am populating lists in a `for()` loop.  A sample of the result is included below.

```
dta <- list(structure(c(128L, 175L), .Dim = 2L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
    c("0", "1")), .Names = ""), class = "table"), structure(c(132L, 
171L), .Dim = 2L, .Dimnames = structure(list(c("0", "1")), .Names = ""), class = "table"), 
    structure(c(130L, 173L), .Dim = 2L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
        c("0", "1")), .Names = ""), class = "table"), structure(c(133L, 
    170L), .Dim = 2L, .Dimnames = structure(list(c("0", "1")), .Names = ""), class = "table"))
```

Each list shows the number of 0's and 1's for a given data set.

```
> head(dta)
[[1]]

  0   1 
128 175 

[[2]]

  0   1 
132 171 

[[3]]

  0   1 
130 173 

[[4]]

  0   1 
133 170
```

The `lapply()` function that I am accustomed to using operates within the lists (i.e. finds the sum of the elements within a given list).  Here I want the average across lists.  Equivocally, I want the mean number of 0's and 1's that occurred in each list (i.e. to average the 0's I want the sum of 128,132,130,133 divide by 4).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: How about `colMeans(matrix(unlist(dta), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try

```
library(reshape2)
library(data.table)
setDT(melt(dta))[, mean(value), Var1]
```

Or

```
colMeans(do.call(rbind, dta))
```

Comment: Great.  Looks like there a many ways!  Thanks for the quick, helpful and informative response to you and all below!

Comment: Do you not have to name the `by` argument in a data table?  I always thought you did

Comment: At least it is not needed in `data.table 1.9.5`. If there are more than one variable, `.(Var1 Var2)]`.  For better understanding, it can be used..

Comment: @RichardScriven what's the difference between `i`, `j` and `by` arguments? it's always `DT[i, j, by]` structure.

Comment: Yeah I guess you're right.  I just hardly ever see it unnamed.  Guess I missed that when I was painstakingly analyzing the DT docs.  Haha

Answer (score 5):

You can use `tapply()`

```
u <- unlist(dta)
tapply(u, names(u), mean)
#      0      1 
# 130.75 172.25
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's approach using `Reduce`

```
Reduce(`+`, dta)/length(dta)
#      0      1 
# 130.75 172.25
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach:

```
sapply(split(unlist(dta), 0:1), mean)
#      0      1 
# 130.75 172.25
```

Answer (score 3):

```
colMeans(matrix(unlist(dta), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
#[1] 130.75 172.25
```

or with dplyr & reshape2:

```
library(reshape2); library(dplyr)
melt(dta) %>% group_by(Var1) %>% summarise(mean = mean(value))
#Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
#
#  Var1   mean
#1    0 130.75
#2    1 172.25
```